# Is it necessary to manually close and dispose of SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

I'm working with legacy code here and there are many instances of `SqlDataReader` that are never closed or disposed. The connection is closed but, I am not sure if it is necessary to manage the reader manually.

Could this cause a slowdown in performance?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Try to avoid using readers like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SomeTable", connection);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
connection.Open();
if (reader != null)
{
      while (reader.Read())
      {
              //do something
      }
}
reader.Close(); // <- too easy to forget
reader.Dispose(); // <- too easy to forget
connection.Close(); // <- too easy to forget
```

Instead, wrap them in using statements:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{

    connection.Open();

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SomeTable", connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        } // reader closed and disposed up here

    } // command disposed here

} //connection closed and disposed here
```

The using statement will ensure correct disposal of the object and freeing of resources.

If you forget then you are leaving the cleaning up to the garbage collector, which could take a while.

Comment: You don't need the .Close() statement in either sample: it's handled by the .Dispose() call.

Comment: This sample doesn't show the underlying connection being closed/disposed, which is the most important thing.

Comment: I don't get it when would the reader be null after "cmd.ExecuteReader"?

Comment: Probably want to check if it .HasRows rather then null.

Comment: I've just run into an error that is thrown when I try to call ExecuteReader on a stored procedure that does not return any results.  When this happens, ExecuteReader fails, throws an exception, and returns null:)

Comment: Also, I agree that the using statements are great, if you're not looking for specific exceptions that are being thrown.  If, on the other hand, you are, then I prefer to use try-catch clauses, although I admit that the majority of my code sticks to the using clauses.

Comment: @Andrew If ExecuteReader throws an exception, how can it return null?

Comment: @JohH: the while (reader.Read()) in the example accomplishes the same as .HasRows, and you need to .Read anyways to advance the reader forward to the first row.

Comment: @csauve  You're right, I guess it must not have returned null.  I'm not sure why I was looking at the value of the SqlDataReader variable.

Comment: actually you don't even need brackets to use `using`

Answer (score 68):

Note that disposing a SqlDataReader instantiated using SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() will **not** close/dispose the underlying connection.

There are two common patterns.  In the first, the reader is opened and closed within the scope of the connection:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = ...)
{
    connection.Open();
    ...
    using(SqlCommand command = ...)
    {
        using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            ... do your stuff ...
        } // reader is closed/disposed here
    } // command is closed/disposed here
} // connection is closed/disposed here
```

Sometimes it's convenient to have a data access method open a connection and return a reader.  In this case it's important that the returned reader is opened using CommandBehavior.CloseConnection, so that closing/disposing the reader will close the underlying connection.  The pattern looks something like this:

```
public SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string commandText)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
        {
            return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Close connection before rethrowing
        connection.Close();
        throw;
    }
}
```

and the calling code just needs to dispose the reader thus:

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = ExecuteReader(...))
{
    ... do your stuff ...
} // reader and connection are closed here.
```

Comment: In the second code snippet where the method returns a SqlDataReader the command is not disposed. Is that ok and is it ok to dispose the command (enclose it in a using block) and then return the reader?

Comment: @alwayslearning that's exactly the scenario that I have......can you close/dispose of the SqlCommand when you are returning the SqlDataReader to the caller?

Comment: This is bad. If you *REALLY* can't bear to use `using`s then call dispose in the `finally {}` block after catch. The way this is written, successful commands would never be closed or disposed.

Comment: @smdrager, if you read the answer closer, he is talking about a method  that returns a reader. If you use .ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection); then by disposing the READER, the connection will be closed. So the calling method only needs to wrap the resulting reader in a using statement. using(var rdr = SqlHelper.GetReader()){ //... } if you were close it in the finally block, then your reader would fail to read because the connection is closed.

Comment: @ganders - coming back to this old post: yes you can and probably should dispose the SqlCommand - updated the example to do so.

Comment: This is a much more detailed and usable answer as it points out multiple use cases.

Comment: Disposing the command disposes the reader and any attempt to read fails, the command should not be disposed in this case.

Answer (score 14):

To be safe, wrap every SqlDataReader object in a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: Fair enough. However, does it actually make a difference in performance if there is no using statement?

Comment: A using statement is the same as wrapping the DataReader code in a try..finally... block, with the close/dispose method in the finally section.  Basically, it just "guarantees" that the object will be disposed of properly.

Comment: This is straight from the link I provided:  "The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object."

Comment: Continued...   "You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler."

Answer (score 5):

Just wrap your SQLDataReader with "using" statement. That should take care of most of your issues.