# Will putting a "using" statement around a DataReader close it?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I usually write my `DataReader` code like this:

```
try
{
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
finally
{
    if (dr != null) { dr.Close(); }
}
```

Is it safe to replace the `try` and `finally` with just a `using` block around the `DataReader`'s creation? The reason I wonder is because in all the Microsoft examples I've seen they use a using for the connection but always explicitly call `Close()` on the `DataReader`.

Heres's an example from
[Retrieving Data Using a DataReader (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(VS.100).aspx):

```
static void HasRows(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, most of the MS examples I've seen are either overly complicated or don't really leverage much of the language features available.  In part it's because they simply roll over the example code from previous releases and really only check that it still runs.  My guess is that this code is not maintained by their brightest because the code is never clever or efficient.

Comment: @NotMe from the quality of the example code, I've suspected *for years* that it's written and maintained by entry-level interns, not the people who actually designed the classes in the first-place. It's things like Microsoft's lackluster .NET documentation that kind of make me look forward to [SO's new documentation expansion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to manually close and dispose of SqlDataReader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744051/is-it-necessary-to-manually-close-and-dispose-of-sqldatareader)

Comment: @Cupcake not a dupe in my opinion. This one here asks if a `using` block will close a data reader, the other one asks if it's required to close it. Not the same thing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's a good point.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. `using` calls Dispose. Calling Dispose on SqlDataReader closes it.

This is psuedo-code of SqlDataReader gleaned from [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/):

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        if( !IsClosed )
            CloseInternal(true);
    }

    private void CloseInternal(bool closeReader)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do some stuff to close the reader itself
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            this.Connection.Abort();
            throw;
        }

        if( this.Connection != null && CommandBehavior.CloseConnection == true )
        {
            this.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Typically, `using()` calls `Dispose()` and that calls `close()` in turn.

In case of a DataReader, the Close is called only when `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` is set (see comments of this article http://weblogs.asp.net/joseguay/archive/2008/07/22/ensure-proper-closure-amp-disposal-of-a-datareader.aspx).

EDIT: [This article](http://codeverity.com/timweaver/usingclosedisposeandfinalize/) says something interesting:

> The Close() method on the
>   SqlDataReader calls an InternalClose()
>   method, which does not call Dispose.
>   Note that previously we stated the
>   correct way to do this was to have
>   your close call dispose. To make it
>   even more confusing the Dispose()
>   method actually calls the Close()
>   method so for this object the order is
>   reversed.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can recall, if an exception occurs in a Using block, then the Dispose method is still called on the object. I usually have a Using statement for all disposable objects, without a Try..Catch.

EDIT: Forgot to say that for some objects, calling Dispose will in turn call Close for that object.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28VS.100%29.aspx), my practice has been to employ a using block for the connection, the command and the reader.  Note that you can stack nested using blocks to lower the indentation cost.

```
static void HasRows(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;",
    connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                        reader.GetString(1));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
            }
            reader.Close();
        }   
    }
}
```