# Login/Register database connection - Build Failed c#

Tags: c#, database, authentication, connection

i try to create a connection from my app to database. Build is started but is failed. I don't understand why. When i press login nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection log = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MODIFIEDforStackOverflow;Initial Catalog=logininfo;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");

        log.Open();

        string newcon=("select username from login where username='"+textBox1.Text+"' and password='"+textBox2.Text+"'");

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(newcon, log);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adp.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
        {
            settext = textBox1.Text;

            welcome wc = new welcome();
            wc.Show();

            this.Hide();
        }else
        {
            label3.Text = "Invalid Login!";
        }
    }
```

Here is my errors:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not copy "obj\Debug\YourTips_App.exe" to "bin\Debug\YourTips_App.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.    YourTips_App
Error       Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\YourTips_App.exe" to "bin\Debug\YourTips_App.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\YourTips_App.exe' because it is being used by another process.  YourTips_App

Thank you!

Comment: Build is failed?You mean any compilation error? You should close the connection after your work in DB,I mean the log.close(); before exiting the method. or enclose this db operations inside using statements.Something like similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185990/sqlcommand-with-using-statement

Comment: Thnak you for your link but not works in my case. This is my errors:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not copy "obj\Debug\YourTips_App.exe" to "bin\Debug\YourTips_App.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. YourTips_App   
Error  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\YourTips_App.exe" to "bin\Debug\YourTips_App.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\YourTips_App.exe' because it is being used by another process. YourTips_App

Comment: 1)Can you please close the visual studio and open again
2)Rebuild the solution and run again,if it's not tried