# Non-invocable member 'DetailsForm.cmd' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sqlcommand

I`m trying to make command work but it doesnt work help please. this error appears at cmd("delete

i have sqlcommand cmd;

```
private void DeleteRecordBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd("delete blacklist1 where idnumber=@Idnumber", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnumber", UID.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: What error is throwing?

Comment: Non-invocable member 'DetailsForm.cmd' cannot be used like a method
red line under cmd("delete blacklist1 where idnumber=@Idnumber", con);

Comment: And for the next error you will get, add a `FROM` clause to your command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
cmd("delete blacklist1 where idnumber=@Idnumber", con);
```

Should be:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("delete blacklist1 where idnumber=@Idnumber", con);
```

However, you should put this inside a `using` block in order to release cmd resources once it finish. See: [SqlCommand with using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185990/sqlcommand-with-using-statement)

Comment: using (cmd = new SqlCommand("delete blacklist1 where idnumber=@Idnumber", con)) worked thank you

Comment: @Luka I would declare cmd variable local to the using block instead of making it a class member.

Comment: I failed to do that