# Copy multiple column values from SqlReader to array?

Tags: c#, sql

How can I generate an array of string that will contain all the column info.
this query will return a single row with multiple columns

```
var rowLines = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                string query = "SELECT I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9,I10,I11,I12,I13,I14,I15 FROM LABEL_OUT WHERE LABEL_NAME='" + labelName + "'";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            rowLines.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

here rowLines will Contain all the column value such as I1,I2,.....I15

Comment: You should also put your `SqlConnection` and your `SqlCommand` [inside a `using` block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23185990/107625) to ensure correct resource release.

Comment: You're already adding the first column to your list.  What is the issue?  Add the other columns the same way.

Comment: Or use a dataset

Comment: I think you forgot to tell what is the expected output

Comment: You aren't handling your [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.7.2) objects, such as SqlConnection properly. You need to dispose of it in a finally block, or wrap it in a using statement to ensure it gets disposed properly.

Comment: Actually this should return your desired output. Maybe you meant that you want all the columns and this is returning many rows with a  single column

Comment: @DreamTeK the number of times `DataSet` is a *good* solution to any problem is *vanishingly* small...

Answer (score 5):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use `DbDataReader.GetValues(object[])`, which populates a pre-existing array with the values from each column:

```
var vals = new object[reader.FieldCount];
while (reader.Read())
{
    reader.GetValues(vals);
    // ... do something with the values
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you will take a single line you could loop on the `reader` using the `FieldCount` and add each element on a `List<string>`. Finally, you could just return it as an `array`.

```
var rowLines = new List<string>();

if (reader.Read())
{
   for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
   {
      rowLines.Add(reader.IsDBNull(i) ? string.Empty : reader[i].ToString());
   }
}

return rowLines.ToArray();
```