# Issue with checking DropDownList's Selected Value exist in Database or Not

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a **web page** and there I have **fields** to **hold some data**.

One of the fields holds the IDs and names of students enrolled in a particular course. I want to be able to enroll **new students** to the course using a drop-down list. If the item **selected** in the drop-down list **already exists** in the Courses Table, I should display an **error message**.

I have a code to do these but when I select an already **existing value** in the drop-down list it **doesn't** show an error message. It assumes it's a new value and throws an **exception** because the Database doesn't accept **duplicate records**.

**How can I solve this problem?**

I use c# language to design this web page in ASP.NET.

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Ceng.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        
        string qs = Request.QueryString["id"]; 
        // Variable qs Keeps CourseID retrieved from query string

        string sv = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value; 
        // Variable sv keeps selected value from DropDownList


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Enrolment as e, Students as s where e.StudentID = s.StudentID and " +
                          "CourseID = " + qs + " and StudentName = '" + sv +"'", con);
        // There are Students, Courses, and Enrolment tables in database
        // Students table columns are StudentID, StudentName, BirthDate
        // Course table columns are CourseID, CourseCode, CourseName, Instructor
        // Enrolment table columns are CourseID and StudentID


        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if(reader.HasRows)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "The selected student is already registered to the course!";
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "The selected student is succesfully registered!";
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;


            SqlDataSource4.Insert();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
```

When i select a name from DropDownList which is not exist in Database, i get proper result.

For example, Think about "Jeff Bezos" is already registered for given course. When i choose "Jeff Bezos" i should get error message but I get exception which says that is duplicate.

Comment: What is the runtime value of the `SELECT` query you're executing?  Are there any matching rows?  The described behavior suggests there are not.

Comment: For variable qs(value retrieved from Query String) 5, and DropDownList selected value Jeff Bazos there are 1 record that means record is exist.

Comment: what returned reader?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you alter your code to use parameters in the SQL not create a SQL statement directly from the UI values - avoid sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Ahmeett_: If a matching record exists then `reader.HasRows` is `true`.  What exactly is the problem here?  When you step through this line by line in your debugger, what specifically happens and where specifically does it fail?

Comment: What is the value of DropDownList for Jeff Bazos and StudentID for Jeff Bazos in database ?

Comment: I would also consider an idisposable here for reference on a `using SqlConnection(...` for that https://stackoverflow.com/q/23185990/125981

Comment: @David expected reader.HasRows is true but it returns false

Comment: @Ahmeett_: You're providing conflicting information.  It seems that your assumptions do not match your observed results.  So... drop the assumptions.  If `reader.HasRows` is `false` then the reader has *no rows*.  There are *no matching records*.  So your query isn't what you expect it to be.  So use your debugger and observe what your query *is*.  What is it?  What exact data is in your tables?  Why do you expect something different?  Elaborate.

Comment: @Thamarai T : Jeff Bezos an element of DropDownList as StudentName and his id is 1.

Comment: @David : SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Enrolment as e, Students as s where e.StudentID = s.StudentID and " +
                          "CourseID = " + qs + " and StudentName = '" + sv +"'", con);

Comment: I mean, what is the output you are getting from `string sv = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;`

Comment: @David when i changed this like that -> SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Enrolment as e, Students as s where e.StudentID = s.StudentID and " +
                          "CourseID = " + qs + " and StudentName = 'Jeff Bezos', con); then reader.HasRows is true

Comment: @ThamaraiT : output is Jeff Bezos

Comment: @Ahmeett_: That's not SQL code.  That's C# code which dynamically *produces* SQL code.  Clearly it's not producing the SQL code you expect it to produce.  So the result you ***assume*** it is producing is incorrect.  So ***stop assuming***.  What is the ***actual SQL code being executed***.  If you debug your code, we can help you.  If all you want to do is insist that your code *should* be right and are looking for someone to agree with you, this isn't the right place for that.

Comment: Try this `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Enrolment as e, Students as s where e.StudentID = s.StudentID and " + "CourseID = " + qs + " and **s.StudentName** = 'Jeff Bezos', con);`

Comment: string qs = Request.QueryString["id"];  Prombel is here i fixed it. Id is an integer value but i choosed string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Parameterize the sql
2. Make the sql a string/text and use it
3. Get rid if bad associative join, create a `INNER` instead
4. use a `using` which implements idisposable
5. Assumptions since you did not post the source of the list
6. Broad assumption on the int vs string for id (int is most common so I go with that)
7. Suggest this might be refactored to methods for better testing

```
       using System;
       using System.Data.SqlClient;
        // more here likely...
        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Ceng.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            string getStudentIdSql = @"
                SELECT s.StudentID 
                FROM Enrolment AS e
                INNER JOIN Students AS s 
                    ON e.StudentID = s.StudentID 
                    AND E.CourseID = @CourseID
                    AND StudentName = @StudentName
            ";
            int courseId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]); // consider tryparse here, I make assumptions on the int also
            // string studentName = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value; // assumption if the values are there
            string studentName = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text; // assumption based on code/comments, key part where it is defined is missing from question
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getStudentIdSql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CourseID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = courseId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = studentName;
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        /* if we wanted to have the rows
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{reader.GetInt32(0)}\t{ reader.GetString(1)}");
                    }
                    */
                        Label1.Visible = true;
                        Label1.Text = "The selected student is already registered to the course!";
                        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    /* basic thing
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                }
                */
                    else
                    {
                        Label1.Visible = true;
                        Label1.Text = "The selected student is succesfully registered!";
                        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        SqlDataSource4.Insert();
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }

                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Ceng.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        int selectedCourseId = 0;
        string qs = Request.QueryString["id"];        

        int.TryParse(qs, out selectedCourseId);

        string sv = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;           

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Enrolment as e, Students as s where e.StudentID = s.StudentID and " +
                          "e.CourseID = @CourseID and s.StudentName = @StudentName", con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CourseID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = selectedCourseId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sv;

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if(reader.HasRows)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "The selected student is already registered to the course!";
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "The selected student is succesfully registered!";
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;


            SqlDataSource4.Insert();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: is there a reason why you select from 2 tables and build the whole cross instead of joining them? Also using * as a selector is bad practice. you should select only the rows you need for speed reasons..