# Delete datagridview cell click event

Tags: c#, sql

Delete datagridview cell click event it says the information was deleted but after clicking the pop-out message the information was still there even if I deleted that certain information. Please help

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(maincon);
            int rfidno = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["rfidno"].FormattedValue.ToString());

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sqlcon.Open();
                da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete tbl_registerStudent where rfidno = '" + rfidno + "'", sqlcon);
                da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("" + rfidno);
                MessageBox.Show("Delete Successfull");
                sqlcon.Close();
                bindGrid();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

This is the code of the bindGrid

````
public void bindGrid()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-EB4EK81\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TACLC;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_registerStudent", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    ```
````

Comment: Could you please share the code of `bindGrid` method ?

Comment: "the information was still there": do you mean in the database or in the UI?

Comment: Your query is wrong  its "delete from tbl_registerStudent "

Comment: Hello @KlausGütter both of them mate, after cliking the cell the information was still there

Comment: Hi @MuhammadWaqasAziz I already tried the "delete from tbl_registerStudent" but the result im getting is still the same

Comment: Hello @Christos the bindGrid code were already been posted. Thanks for asking, forget to post that

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sqlcon.Open();
            da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from tbl_registerStudent where rfidno = '" + rfidno + "'", sqlcon);
            da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("" + rfidno);
            MessageBox.Show("Delete Successfull");
            sqlcon.Close();
            bindGrid();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Hello. I am using the code that you've shared but the result that I'm getting is the same as before

Comment: Hi Johh, In that case, please check the value of ExecuteNonQuery() if it is -1 means it is not successful. Try deleting the same from SQL query to check if you get any constrains error.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you have to open the SqlConnection, then execute your command, bind the result and last to not forget to close the connection:

```
public void bindGrid()
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-EB4EK81\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TACLC;Integrated Security=True");
   con.Open()
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_registerStudent", con);
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   sda.Fill(dt);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
   con.Close();
}
```

A better approach, in order you don't remember to close the `SqlConnection` is to use a `using` statement and let the compiler to generate this call for you.

```
public void bindGrid()
{
   // This should be normally placed in a configuration file and read it from there. 
   string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-EB4EK81\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TACLC;Integrated Security=True";

   using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
       con.Open()
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_registerStudent", con);
       SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       sda.Fill(dt);
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;  
   }
}
```

Furthermore, since [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) class inherits from [DbCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand?view=netcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and the latter implements the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netcore-3.1) interface, you should keep in mind that you should use once more the `using` statement and used resources to be released. For furthermore info on this, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185990/sqlcommand-with-using-statement).

That being said the suggested approach is the following:

```
public void bindGrid()
{
   // This should be normally placed in a configuration file and read it from there. 
   string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-EB4EK81\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TACLC;Integrated Security=True";

   using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
       con.Open()
       using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_registerStudent", con))
       {
           SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           sda.Fill(dt);
           dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;  
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Christos. I've used the code that you shared which is the code #1and #2. It is working for me but I still got the same results as before sad to say

Comment: @JohnSanityCOPH Hi ! One question, could you please place a breakpoint at `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` and verify that the data are loaded from the database ? It they are loaded, then we should look somewhere else for finding the solution of the problem. Otherwise, we don't have the data, and we can't tell. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Christos! I've located the problem now and its solved. The problem is in my database the data type of the "rfidno" is varchar and i put was "int" upon changing the int to string it solved. Thank you for the comment it solved my problem

Comment: Hi @JohnSanityCOPH ! Sounds good. You found it :) Kudos.