# SQL returning incorrect amount of rows

Tags: c#, sql, oledbdatareader

I am trying to get 2 rows of data from my MS Access Database using an SQL command and using the datareader but it's only returning one row of data. I don't exactly know how the datareader works so I think it might be from something I incorrectly coded with it. The SQL command should be fine cause I when I run it in an MS Access Query it works. Do you know what is wrong with my code? [Edit: I am not actually trying to get the number of rows, that's just for testing. Below the code snippet I posted, my program actually loads the data into an array so that the 2 integers can be compared and the smallest one is chosen.]

```
if (passageID != 1)
        {
            Connect(fileName);

            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
            com.Connection = cxn;
            com.CommandText = "SELECT PO.OptionID_FK FROM PassageOption AS PO WHERE PO.PassageID_FK = @passageID;";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passageID", passageID);


            OleDbDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();

            int numRows = r.RowCount;

            if (r.HasRows)
            {
                int i = 0;
                int[] optionIDs = new int[2];

                while (r.Read())
                {
                    optionIDs[i] = (int)r[i]; // It gives me the following error, the second time it runs, when i = 1; System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
                    i++;
                }

                if (optionIDs[0] < optionIDs[1])
                {
                    j = optionIDs[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    j = optionIDs[1];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are looking at "FieldCount". You need the row count.

Comment: In addition: _not_ putting the data reader into a `using` block will lead to connection pool leaks.

Comment: ...and bear in mind that there isn't a row count property, because that would likely be an expensive operation as it would need you to have iterated the entire result set. Do you actually need to get the rowcount, or are you just using that for testing? (If you need to get the count, you're better off using a `SELECT COUNT...` query...)

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` be more performant than firing a reader and getting the count from the reader?

Comment: @UweKeim: I think it would depend on the situation. If OP is sure that only 2 records will be returned the looping through the records is not likely to be a problem & probably no slower than a query for the count followed by the required query. If there was the possibility of getting millions of records returned - that would be a different matter.

Comment: @Wheels73 I OleDB doesn't have a row count.  I just checked but still even if I don't count and I just look at the data it returns, it returns one row even though if I run the same query in the database directly, it returns 2 rows.

Comment: @DuaneGrech - Correct. oledbreader is a forward only dataset. You would have to read to the end to get the count. sorry my wording sort of suggests a row count property exists.

Comment: @UweKeim  I am actually using the count, just for testing purposes. I need the data itself which I do recover in the code below that. Should I add it to the code snippet?

Comment: @MattGibson  I am actually using the count, just for testing purposes. I need the data itself which I do recover in the code below that. Should I add it to the code snippet?

Comment: @UweKeim How do you put the data reader in a using block?

Comment: Yes. If your problem is with retrieving all the rows, we'll need to see the code that tries to retrieve the rows.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755687/should-i-be-using-sqldatareader-inside-a-using-statement) on how to put the data reader into a using block.

Comment: @MattGibson I added the code

Answer (score 1):

A datareader doesn't know how many rows will be returned by your select query until it has read all the data from the underlying stream coming from the database.

The FieldCount property returns the number of fields in your query and it is exactly one for your current query.

To know the rows you need to Read them one by one or use a DataTable

```
int numRows = 0;
while(r.Read())
{
    // do your task with the current IDataRecord
    numRows++;
}

Console.WriteLine($"There are {numRows} rows");
```

Or filling a DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader());
Console.WriteLine($"There are {dt.Rows.Count} rows");
```

The two methods above are useful if you plan to use the data returned (in the reader array or in the table rows array), but if you just want to know how many rows exists then it is better (albeit minimal with only two rows returned) to change your query to:

```
com.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PassageOption AS PO 
                    WHERE PO.PassageID_FK = @passageID;";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passageID", passageID);
int numRows = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();
```

No reader needed when you want one row with one field, just ExecuteScalar

**EDIT to update with your last edit**

This line fails

```
optionIDs[i] = (int)r[i];
```

because you have only one field in your query. The indexer i should be used only to refer to the optionIDs array not to extract a field at position 1 from the reader. There is no field at position 1, just use

```
optionIDs[i] = (int)r[0];
```

for every Read call

Comment: You loop over the DataTable.Rows with _foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)_ and then get the single field with _Convert.ToInt32(row[0])_ There are many ways to do it but this is material for another question

Comment: However, the operation that fills the datatable uses the same OleDbDataReader. This is ininfluent with only two records and a local database like Access, but this is potentially an hit on the performance if used on large result sets. Essentially, when filling and then looping on a datatable, you are looping two times on your data. Prefer the Read approach for performance or use an ORM to further simplify things

Answer (score 0):

```
int numRows = r.FieldCount;
```

**FieldCount Property** gets the number of columns in the row not the number of records.

You are selecting only `OptionID_FK` single Column from the table. `FieldCount` will show you 1.

**Getting no. of rows**

```
OleDbDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();
int rowCount = 0;
if (r.HasRows)  
{  
    while (r.Read())  
    {  
       rowCount++;     
    }  
}
r.Close();
```

Comment: Or simply `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`.

Comment: Yes that is possible. Your are right. I tried to give solution within his question details only. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data reader only has one column in it, the column you selected, `PO.OptionID_FK`. Therefore in your loop, when `i` is 1:

```
optionIDs[i] = (int)r[i]; // It gives me the following error, the second time it runs, when i = 1; System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
```

...you're trying to select the second *column* from the datareader (`r[i]`), which doesn't exist.

The way DataReader works is that whenever you do `r.read`, you're moved onto the next row, and your `r` "array" variable is refreshed with all the column values from the new row. The array index `r[n]` selects the nth *column* of the reader, not the nth *row*. So you should just use:

```
optionIDs[i] = (int)r[0];
```

...which will set your optionIDs value with the value of the DataReader's first (zeroth) column for the current row.

Comment: Hi I managed to fix it on my own by turning the optionIDs into a list passing a column name to the reader, how do I make that clear on the post. Sry but I am new to the site.