# Does the SQL connection not get closed if you put the datareader in a using block?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, connection-pooling, datareader, connection-timeout

So, I recently inherited a large project that uses the following data access pattern; unfortunately, this is resulting in a massive number of timeout exceptions related to connection pooling.

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached"

It clear that the connections are leaking and not getting closed properly.
So, the framework has a `DataAccess` class with the method `GetDataReader`.

When the data reader is referenced, it is placed inside a using block, but connections are still leaking.

Does the fact that the connection is not explicitly closed or placed in a using block the reason why the connections are getting leaked?

Normally, I would wrap the connection in a using block AND wrap the data reader in a using block.

Obviously, this framework is very flawed, but would somehow using the option `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` for the data reader resolve this issue?

None the external code accesses the `SqlConnection` directly and has to go through this `DataAccess` class.

```
public IDataReader GetDataReader(QueryDto dto)
{
    DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(dto.DatabaseName);

    DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(dto.StoredProcedureName);

    if (dto.Params.Length > 0)
    {
        cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(dto.StoredProcedureName, dto.Params);
    }

    dto.Command = cmd;

    cmd.CommandTimeout = dto.Timeout;
    cmd.Connection = db.CreateConnection();

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        // Handle Exception here...
        throw;
    }

    return rdr;
}
```

Usage in some static repository class:

```
var query = new QueryDto
{
    DatabaseName = "SomeDatabase",
    Params = parms,
    StoredProcedureName = "StoredProcedureName"
};

using (IDataReader dr = dataAccess.GetDataReader(query))
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will putting a using() around a datareader close it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157276/will-putting-a-using-around-a-datareader-close-it)

Comment: Actually, my question is not about if putting a using stmt on a data reader would dispose/close properly. It's if the underlying SQL connection will close when the connection is not wrapped in a using block

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the using statement is around a function that has open resources embedded in it. The using will not dispose of the connection that is opened inside `GetDataReader`. I think your are correct that the Connection itself needs to be in a using block. The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) only calls Dispose on the object that is passed in, not any nested resources.