# SqlConnection SqlCommand SqlDataReader IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` all implement the `IDisposable` interface. I read about a best practice to always wrap `IDisposables` into a `using` block.

So, my common scenario for querying data would look something like this (in greater context of course a mapping tool like linq2sql would be suitable, but lets just assume we want to use this approach here):

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("myConnectionstring"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("myQuery", cn))
    {
        // maybe add sql parameters
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader())
        {
             // read values from reader object
             return myReadValues;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way or could that be considered overkill? I am a little unsure about this level of nesting `using` blocks, but of course i want to do it the correct way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is 100% the correct way. If a class leverages `IDisposable` it should be wrapped in a `using` statement to ensure that the `Dispose()` method is called. Further, communicating with an outside technology -unmanaged at that -like SQL Server shouldn't be taken lightly. The `SqlCommand` object implements `IDisposable` for a very good reason. The code below is the `Dispose()` method for the `SqlCommand` object:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        this._cachedMetaData = null;
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

and as you can see, it's releasing a reference to the `_cachedMetaData` object so that it too can get cleaned up.

Comment: thanks for your answer, especially for detail about `SqlCommands`'s dispose - exactly the information i was looking for!

Comment: @Chips_100, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: Just an FYI, "using" is syntactic sugar for a try --> finally block where the finally calls Dispose. Don't do it that way though - use the using keyword. :)

Comment: "it's releasing a reference to the `_cachedMetaData` object" - but in the OP's example, the _`cachedMetaData` object would become eligible for GC as soon as its containing `SqlCommand` goes out of scope, which is potentially sooner without the `using` statement than with it.  NB I'm not arguing against calling Dispose: it's probably better not to rely on knowledge of the internals of `SqlCommand` and just follow the pattern blindly.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following way of typography to get the code closer to the left:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("myConnectionstring"))
using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("myQuery", cn))
using (SqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader())
{
     // read values from reader object
     return myReadValues;
}
```

As other already pointed out, using three nested `using` blocks is correct though.

Comment: If later on you go auto-identing the rest of your code (i.e.: Ctrl + K + D in Visual Studio), you lose that.

Comment: thanks, i didn't know of 'stacking' `using` declarations before. It's a nice thing to have, alghough i could for example not use that, if i need to add parameters to the SqlCommand. Thanks again for the info!

Comment: @Renan Actually I don't lose it in VS2012. If I remember correctly, VS2010 did support this "using stack" too...

Comment: I don't think this code works, since the connection is never opened. Stacking it like this looks good, but it's just not viable since there's always stuff that needs to be done (cn.Open(), cm.Parameters.AddWithValue() etc)

Answer (score 4):

That is the correct way, if you will be done with the reader. Sometimes, you need the reader to remain open (maybe your method *returns* it), so it disposing the reader right away would not work. In those cases, there is an overload of the ExecuteReader that can help you:

```
var cn = new SqlConnection("myConnectionstring");
var cm = new SqlCommand("myQuery", cn);
var reader = cm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
return reader;
```

This will keep the connection and the reader open. Once the reader is closed/disposed, it will also close (and dispose) the connection as well.

```
using(var reader = GetReader()) //which includes the code above
{
   ...
} // reader is disposed, and so is the connection.
```

Comment: Your `GetReader` example is flawed, as it doesn't dispose the connection if `new SqlCommand` or `ExecuteReader` throws.  See the following answer for a more complete implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/744307/13087

Comment: @Joe Good point, this is not a complete implementation (thanks for the link). The main thing I wanted to point out was the usage of `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` when the reader needs to remain open.

Answer (score 2):

This is not overkill. A `using` block is good practice because it ensures that the `Dispose()` method of the object will be called, even if an exception is thrown.

There is a name for this kind of thing, though. It's called **code sugar**. So:

```
using (foo bar = new foo()) { //...snip }
```

Is short hand code for:

```
foo bar = null;
Exception error = null;
try {
    bar = new foo();
    // ...snip
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    error = ex;
}
finally {
    if (bar != null) bar.Dispose();
    if (error != null) throw error;
}
```

Either form is equal to the other, they're just different ways to write the same thing. In other words, same difference between `for` and `while`: they do basically the same thing but are used in different ways.

`using` is preferred because it makes the code shorter and more readable, and automates the disposal for you. As to whether you should use it, though, don't listen to people who say you should *always* do something. It's good practice, granted, but knowing **when to use**, **why to use** and **the benefits and consequences of using, or not using** something is worth way more than **doing something because people say you should**.

[Eren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16986224/2263584) has an example of a case where you wouldn't want to have a `using` block for the `reader`.

Answer (score 1):

Yep that's correct. You can miss the braces out in nested using as they are one statement, but  I don't feel that adds to readability.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any point in disposing the `SqlCommand`. The `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader` should be disposed of though.

The `SqlConnection` because it won't close by itself when it goes out of scope.

The `SqlDataReader` can keep the `SqlConnection` busy until the reader is closed.

Not even MSDN examples dispose of the `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Huh? It implements Idisposable, so it's going to get disposed of. Why would you leave it floating about, until (if) the GC kicks in.

Comment: It is widely accepted as a best practice to dispose of any class instance that implements `IDisposable`.  The question isn't Why dispose of the `SqlCommand` but rather Why Not?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that it is really not more important than getting anything else non-crucial disposed of. @TonyHopkinson, do you run the GC after every object you create goes out of scope? No? Because there is no point. Dispose also uses clock cycles. You should either argue against Garbage Collection in general, or not at all.

Comment: There are classes such as SqlCommand, DataTable that implement IDisposable, but all they do is set a private reference to null, which has no effect if the containing instance is going out of scope anyway.  I'd normally dispose SqlCommand, but strictly speaking this answer is correct, omitting the dispose will have no adverse effect.

Comment: Agree with Evan Lewis, and no I don't run GC, except in edge case scenarios. It's far more important to remember to Dispose, than to remember a couple of cases where you could get away with not doing it. Not to mention the inherent scoping it gives you..

Answer (score -2):

I'm not an expert but i know that the using is translated into a try/finally block maybe you can wrap the SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader into a unique try/finally

```
try {
     // code here with SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader
}
finally
{
  // Dispose call on SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader
 }
```

Comment: Wasn't me who marked you down, but don't try this. It's not equivalent, and in the event of an exception will leak like a sieve and possibly raise even more exceptions an should raise a pile of warnings from the compiler.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I answered just to have a feedback. Can you explain further why it's not equivalent? thank you very much!

Comment: If sql connection connect raises an exception. Finally executes and then you get a null reference exception on the sqlcommand. To get round that you have to test for nil.

Answer (score -2):

SqlConnection Not Recognized as IDisposable
Problem Description

Developers encounter an error where SqlConnection is not recognized as IDisposable when trying to use it in a using statement. This issue hinders proper database connectivity and can be frustrating for developers trying to interact with a SQL Server database in their ASP.NET Core application.
Problem Symptoms

```
Error message: "type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'."
SqlConnection methods like Open() and Close() are not recognized.
```

Root Cause

The problem occurs when there's a conflict or confusion in the namespaces being used. The using System.Data.SqlClient; directive may conflict with another SqlConnection class, leading to the error.
Solution

To resolve the issue, explicitly specify the fully qualified name of SqlConnection using the complete namespace:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myCon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlDatasource);
```

By using the fully qualified name, we ensure that the correct SqlConnection class is used, addressing the namespace conflict and allowing the SqlConnection object to be recognized as IDisposable.
Steps to Implement the Solution

```
Replace using System.Data.SqlClient; with using System.Data.SqlClient; in the code file.
Update the SqlConnection declaration to use the fully qualified name:
 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myCon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlDatasource);
```