# Problems with Open/Close sql connection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I hope you forgive my beginner's head. I am having some problems with a code designed to open a connect to a SQL Server database.

As you can see `frmManageAppointment` form is loaded from a different Winform. So far so good. Upon loading, the `Connect()` part of the code kicks in and connects to my SQL Server database. So far so good.

I have a second script that load upon pressing the Save button on the form (basically saving a variety of textboxes and such). My guess is that the second instance of conn in the `MakeAppointment` code somehow closed the connection, based on the error I am getting.

I know I am not handling the script correctly so I would appreciate some help.

```
namespace Scheduler1
{
    public partial class frmManageAppointment : Form
    {
        public frmManageAppointment()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmManageAppointment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connect();

            txtDBConnection.Text = "Connected";
        }

        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSurname.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Απαιτείται το Επίθετο του Εξεταζόμενου!");
                return;
            }

            if (MakeAppointment())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Επιτυχής Προσθήκη!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ανεπιτυχής Προσθήκη");
            }
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            string conString = "Data Source=DIMITRIS-PC\\DIMITRISSQL;Initial Catalog=AppointmentDB;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);

            conn.Open();

            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Closed");
            }
            else if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Open");
            }
        }

        public Boolean MakeAppointment()
        {
            string conString = "Data Source=DIMITRIS-PC\\DIMITRISSQL;Initial Catalog=AppointmentDB;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
            string sql = "INSERT INTO Appointmentdbo(Date, Time, Name, Surname, DOB, PatientID, Comments) VALUES ('" + dtpDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + comboTime.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtSurname.Text + "','" + dtpDOB.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + txtID.Text + "','" + txtComments.Text + "')";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You open a new connection every time those functions are called, and `MakeAppointment` never issues `conn.Open();`...

Comment: Don't reuse your connection. Create a new `SqlConnection` locally anywhere it is needed and wrap it in a `using` block so it is closed/disposed after use. Follow that design and your code becomes easier to read and also more robust because you do not have a bunch of dependencies on a single connection instance.

Comment: Your `Connect` method declared a new local variable (`conn`) and opens a connection with it. It then exits, meaning that the `conn` variable goes out of scope and may be garbage collected. In your `MakeAppointment` method you declare a new local variable of the same name-- however, it is a different variable. You never open it. That is the problem.

Comment: I suspected....so basically the approach to have a Connect() function and a MakeAppointment function cant work....

Comment: Of course it *can*, if  you save your connection or use a connection pool. But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692050/best-practice-for-reusing-sqlconnection

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments pointed out, you're creating a connection (the `conn` object in `Connect()`, opening it, and then `conn` goes out of scope.  It's the `conn` object here that IS the open connection.

Here's the shortest way to get this to work, but as the comments also state, this isn't really that great, either.  I laid this out to explain exactly what you were doing wrong/why what you had wasn't working.  Below this I have an example with `using` statements.

```
public class frmManageAppointment : Form {

    SqlConnection conn; //private variable available to all methods in this class

    private void frmManageAppointment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connect();
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CloseConn(); //new method here
        this.Close();
    }

    void CloseConn() {
        //we want to close/dispose the connection obect
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }


    public void Connect()
    {
        string conString = "<constring>";
        conn = new SqlConnection(conString); //removed type here so conn now the class level variable
        conn.Open();
        //rest of code snipped        
    }

    public Boolean MakeAppointment()
    {
        string sql = "<sql string>"; //btw, the way you're generating this string is ... not ideal.  Google sql injection
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); //conn is our global variable, which we're assuming here is still open/valid (not ideal)
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
    }
```

}

The problem with this is that your form will be open for an indefinite length of time.  This probably won't be an issue with a small app connecting to a local database where the app is the only thing connecting, but leaving the connection open wastes server resources and you have no guarantee that the `conn` object is still valid when you later try to use it in `MakeAppointment()`.  You could add checks that it is actually open and call `Connect()` again if it's not, but that's a bunch of work for no gain.  A better pattern/habit to adopt when working with databases (or any network resource) is to only open them when you need to do work and close/release them as soon as you're done.  So that said, here's what your code would look like.

```
public class frmManageAppointment : Form {

    //no need for a Connect() method, conn global variable, or a CloseConn() method
    //your other methods pertaining to the UI would need to be copied over

    public Boolean MakeAppointment()
    {
        string sql = "<sql string>"; //again, what you're doing here is bad
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connectionstring>") {
            conn.Open();
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You only open the connection immediately before using it (the only place you're doing work in this example is in `MakeAppointment()`), and by wrapping the connection and command in `using` statements, they're automatically disposed of (by calling those objects `Dispose()` method) as soon as they go out of scope.