# Async await from aspnet controller down call stack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await

Given the following code snippet of an `aspnet` controller, is it a requirement to have `async`/`await` at the top level, or is it valid to return a `Task`?

The scenario assumes there is some IO (data access) that uses async in underlying code in the repository.

**controller**

```
public class SomeController
{
    private readonly ISomeService service;

    public SomeController(ISomeService service) => _service = service;

    public async Task<SomeResult> GetAsync()
    {
        return await _someService.GetAsync();
    }
}
```

**service**

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly ISomeRepo repo;

    public SomeController(ISomeRepo repo) => _repo = repo;

    public async Task<SomeResult> GetAsync()
    {
        return await _repo.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Thus in the above, is the `async`/`await` required?  It compiles fine without.  [Async Fixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SemihOkur.AsyncFixer) suggests async await is not required either.

This is a great article:

https://saebamini.com/common-async-and-await-misconceptions/#you-need-to-use-asyncawait-in-the-whole-call-stack

But this is contradictory to other bits of information.

[When should I use Async Controllers in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30566848/when-should-i-use-async-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net

https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-async-and-await-in-asp-net-what-do-these-keywords-mean/

[async/await in MVC controller's action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244301/async-await-in-mvc-controllers-action)

But the question is, what is the correct implementation for `async`/`await` in the above aspnet context?

Feel free to list various caveats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's important to note that either way, the code is asynchronous.

That said, I generally recommend people to start with `async`/`await` everywhere and then only elide the keywords in trivial cases. There are several [caveats when eliding `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), including exceptions and `using` statements. So as a general rule, if the implementation is truly trivial (literally just "forward to another method"), then feel free to elide `async`/`await`; everywhere else, keep the `async`/`await` keywords. They have minimal overhead and guarantee correct semantics for nontrivial methods.