# Update SqlCommand- Does not update in Database

Tags: c#, database, sqlcommand

this doesn't update in my database table.  Have I over-looked something?

The values are in the textboxes fine.  No errors show, weird.

```
          using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = UKMAN1NB10038\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = TheVets; Integrated Security = True"))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE OwnerTable SET Owner_Fname =@OwnerFname , Owner_Lname = @OwnerLname, Owner_HouseNo = @OwnerHouse, Owner_Street = @OwnerStreet, Owner_County = @OwnerCounty, Owner_PostCode = @OwnerPost, Owner_Tele = @OwnerTele, Owner_Email = @OwnerEmail WHERE Owner_ID = '" + CB_EDIT_OWNER.SelectedText + "'", connection);

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = connection;



            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerFname", TXT_EDIT_FNAME.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerLname", TXT_EDIT_LNAME.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerHouse", TXT_EDIT_HOUSE.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerStreet", TXT_EDIT_STREET.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerCounty", TXT_EDIT_COUNTY.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerPost", TXT_EDIT_POSTCODE.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerTele", TXT_EDIT_TELE.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerEmail", TXT_EDIT_EMAIL.Text);

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use parameters for all of your things, but then you use string adding for `CB_EDIT_OWNER.SelectedText`? why is that not a parameter too? (It is very possible that owner_id not being a parameter is the source of your problem)

Comment: Probably the ID... check its runtime value. And consider adding it as a parameter too, it might not be safe for scripting like this. `command` should also be wrapped in using() { }, like the connection.

Comment: Use the debugger, look what `CB_EDIT_OWNER.SelectedText` returns

Comment: @dlatikay command really doesn't. The only reason SqlCommand is disposable is becuse it inherits from `System.ComponentModel.Component`. If nothing is subscribing to it's `Disposed` event there is no need to dispose it. It falls in to the same category as `DataTable` or `Task`, both of those are disposable too but you don't need to dispose of them either normally.

Comment: Sorted it!  Thanks @TimSchmelter   - SelectedItem not selectedText

Comment: @elszeus if it was a simple bug on your part you can delete your question or post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain in this case I have written literally thousands of lines of code in vain, and ill-advised many of my poor fellow developers. Is it not recommendable to always stick to the `IDisposable` > using() pattern because we never know if future implementations may start to need it? As for example the ODP.NET implementation of DbCommand does. Also, there is http://stackoverflow.com/a/16985968/1132334

Comment: Okay, chill out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `SelectedItem` not `SelectedText` on the `combobox`

Replace `CB_EDIT_OWNER.SelectedText` with:

```
CB_EDIT_OWNER.SelectedItem
```

Then this should work.

Comment: If you want to allow people to type in their own values from items not in the combo box's list then you must use `SelectedText`.

Comment: how often are you going to want the user to enter their own values in a combobox?