# C# Windows Form with SQL Memory Jump

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, forms

I'm working on a program that queries a local SQL Server database. The basic setup is a main form with buttons that take you to new forms for each task. The main window uses about 20MB or memory. The other forms that are using less than that. No big deal.

EXCEPT:

Whenever I open a form that contains to run a SQL script/connections, the memory jumps up 1-2GB per form. What I can't figure out is, I'm not actually opening the db connection until a button is clicked. On form initialization, the connection is not open. When I do click a button, the connection opens, the script is executed, and then the connection closes, but there is no noticeable change in memory usage during that process.

Moreover, the memory us not release when I close or dispose of the form. I tried running a GC.collect and that did nothing.

So my questions are: why the large memory jump, and why doesn't it release when I close the form.

I'm new to coding so there may be something I'm completely overlooking, but I can't figure it out. I've reached out to an instructor at my school and there were stumped as well. If there is any more information you need to answer the question, please let me know.

Edit: Here's the code. I know I need to add parameters, I'm getting there.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace KingKit
{
    public partial class DatabaseRepairForm : Form
    {
        public DatabaseRepairForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //DBCC BUTTON
        private void ResetSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                
                Ux_connectionFailed.Visible = false;

                //CONNECTION AND SCRIPT EXECUTION ATTEMPT


                //ESTABLISH CONNECTION
                string dbname = DBNameInput.Text;
                string connection = "server=localhost\\King;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "Database=" + dbname + "; connection timeout=10";

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
                SqlCommand dbcc = new SqlCommand("dbcc checkdb(" + dbname + ") with tableresults", conn);

                conn.Open();
                //CONNECTION CHECK
                if (conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    Ux_connectionCheck.Visible = true;
                    Ux_connectionLabel.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Ux_connectionLabel.Visible = true;
                    Ux_connectionFailed.Visible = true;

                }

                //CODE EXECUTION
                SqlDataReader reader = dbcc.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Ux_repairDisplay.Items.Add(reader["MessageText"].ToString());
                }
                conn.Close();
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        //EXIT BUTTON
        private void Ux_appExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant form code. 1 or 2 GB of memory for a simple form is not good at all, and as per the description the database connection is not the cause. Maybe the form does something else like allocating a big data structure up front, but all we can do right now is to guess.

Comment: @Alejandro added the code. thanks.

Comment: `Ux_repairDisplay` is probably growing rather large as there will add multiple lines per table to the list. If there's an error there could be many, many more depending on how many errors are encountered. Try adding `WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS` to the query to eliminate the noise from the dbcc. You probably only care about errors anyway.

Comment: @fourwhey I really need the messages to display, it's not really for me, it's for the end user. But, I tried your suggestion and I'm still getting the memory surge. It happens as soon as the form is created, not when any buttons are clicked.

Comment: > I'm still getting the memory surge.
What else is on the form then?  I don't see anything in your code that would cause what you've described. On the opening of the form, prior to doing anything memory utilization should be low unless you have a bunch of data loaded into it.

Comment: @fourwhey The form is all buttons that execute SQL scripts just like this one where the connection is opened and closed with each button. The only things other than the buttons are a text box for the db name and the list box for the dbcc output, some small picture boxes and labels.

Answer (score 0):

There are things you'll need to do to the code on button click to ensure proper cleanup. But before we even get there, are you saying just constructing the form causes the memory surge?

1. Are you sure the main form (that spawns this form) doesn't call any of its methods, causing data to start being read?
2. Try putting a breakpoint on your InitializeComponent() and start stepping inside it, and monitor if any particular line triggers the surge.

Now on to the code itself. As you can see in MSDN, [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection), [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand), and [SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader) are all `IDisposable`. You should put disposables in a [using()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement to ensure they get disposed properly when out of scope, or when Exceptions occur. [Also see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985876/sqlconnection-sqlcommand-sqldatareader-idisposable).

When starting out with .NET it's probably not obvious what is Disposable and what isn't, but a general rule is that all external resources (databases, files, network connections) and graphical objects (Forms, Controls, Fonts) are most likely disposable. You don't normally need to dispose Controls on the form because the Form (acting as a Container) will dispose them when disposing itself. Every other IDisposables you create, you need to clean up yourself.

As for `Ux_repairDisplay`, there's probably nothing you can do there (except, as mentioned in one of the comments, limiting the noise). If you do need the noise, maybe also put a number limit in your `while` loop so that if you get a million messages, it doesn't get out of hand.

Comment: Constructing the form is what is causing the memory surge. Before I got any responses on this, I commented out everything between the braces for the ResetButton_Click. I didn't think this would do anything since the code isn't executed until the click and I was right, the memory surge still occurred. I will definitely go back add in using statements, but it doesn't seem like that's going to resolve this issue. I guess it's possible that the main form that spawns this one could be responsible, but all it has are buttons that open different forms

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion of putting breakpoints and stepping through the code? Especially inside the `InitializeComponent()` method. There might be a control in there trying to do something it shouldn't.