# ExecuteReader Timing Out

Tags: c#, sql-server, executereader

I'm trying to create a login page.

I get the users ID and password as parameters, and I want to access my database and compare them, but when I execute the query using `ExecuteReader`, the query always times out.

The database itself is very very small, only with about 5 or 6 users so it shouldn't be timing out......

```
SqlConnection cnn = null;
string connectionString = null;

connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-A5GR284\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Chat_DB;Integrated Security=True";

cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cnn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users", cnn);

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetString(1));
    }

    reader.NextResult();
}

cnn.Close();
```

The reader will timeout before entering the 'while loop'

Comment: Try using the debugger to see what's going on. Also, have a look at `using` for the SQL part, so that it autocloses your connection for you (it implements `IDisposeable` - as per here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985876/sqlconnection-sqlcommand-sqldatareader-idisposable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8), `ExecuteReader()`

> Sends the `CommandText` to the `Connection` and builds a `SqlDataReader`.

Generally, if you get a timeout here, the problem is with the database connection. Looking at your code, I think the connection string in the `connetionString` is the problem. Check to see if it really is the connection string you're looking for. Also check for invisible characters in the same connection string.

Comment: Thank You! The problem was indeed the database connection.

Comment: I am glad I could help you. Please upvote the answer if you think it was useful, so as other people get helped as well.