# Can I keep a SqlDataReader "alive" after closing connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, sqldatareader

Is there any way to access a `SqlDataReader` after the connection is closed?

Or is there any objects equivalent to `SqlDataReader` that I can store the reader into them and process on the objects later?

I'm receiving a pivot dataset from the server, so I can't use normal classes to process this kind of data, my model looks like this :

```
public class OneToNinetyNine
{
    public List<Cities> listCities;
    public string CityID;
    public DateTime DateFrom;
    public DateTime DateTo;
    // this is the reader that I attempt to pass to the views 
    public SqlDataReader SqlReader; 
}
```

Comment: No, just use your own class to store the fields.

Comment: You need to read the data into a `DataSet`, or `DataTable` using the `Load` method, then you can close the connection.

Comment: @Ben: he doesn't even need a `DataTable`/`DataSet` if the already uses a `SqlDataReader`. He just needs to initialize the class appropriately from the fields of the reader.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, is that going to work after he closes the connection?

Comment: @Ben: you cannot use the reader if the connection is closed but therefor you have the class and it's fields which are not related to the database.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that is a dynamic resultset, I can not store it in a class

Comment: @hoangnnm:What's the meaning of this? Maybe you could use a LINQ provider like `Linq-To-Sql` and use it's [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) capabilities.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I solved by using a DataTable, thanks anyway

Comment: @hoangnnm: if you can load a `DataTable` you could also load a typed `List<OneToNinetyNine>`(or whatever).

Comment: @TimSchmelter but there are dynamic columns! Or maybe I'm not understanding your point correctly!

Comment: @hoangnnm: yi've not enough informations to provide something helpful. What is dynamic, what is static? You could loop all fields of a `DataReader` even if you don't know the columns. So you could load for example a `List<string>` as property in our class for the dynamic part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `DataReader` after the connection is closed, as it needs to use the connection to retrieve the data from the data source.

You need to read the data into a `DataSet`, or `DataTable` using the `Load` method, then you can close the connection.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick with the DataSet

Answer (score 4):

You can store the data from an `SqlDataAdapter` into a `DataSet` for future use:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("sql statement");
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mycommand))
{
    adapter.Fill(ds);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to access a SqlDataReader after the connection is closed?

No. Once the Connection is closed, the reader is unable to read data from the connection.

However, it is possible to **invert the relationship lifespan between `DataReader` and `Connection`** by using the `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteReaderAsync` calls with `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` specified. In this mode, the Connection is closed when the Reader is Closed (or Disposed).

Long lived data readers with `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` can be useful when you do not necessarily want to retrieve and materialize all data in the query all-at-once, with use cases such as data paging or take-while type lazy evaluation. This is Option 2, below.

**Option 1 : Open Connection, Retrieve and Materialize all Data, and Close Everything**

As with the other answers, in many instances for small, definite data fetches it is preferable to open Connection, Create Command, Execute Reader and fetch and materialize all data in one go like so:

```
public async Task<Foo> GetOneFoo(int idToFetch)
{
   using (var myConn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
   using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Col2, ... FROM Foo WHERE Id = @Id"))
   {
      await myConn.OpenAsync();
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", idToFetch);
      using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
      {
         var myFoo = new Foo
         {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
            ... etc
         }
         return myFoo; // We're done with our Sql data access here
      } // Reader Disposed here
   } // Command and Connection Disposed here
}
```

**Option 2 : Open Connection, Execute Command, and use a Long Lived Reader**

Using `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`, we can create a long-lived reader and defer closing of the Connection until the `Reader` is no longer needed.

In order to prevent data access objects like `DataReaders` bleeding into higher layer code, a `yield return` generator can be used to manage reader lifespans -  while at the same time ensuring the reader (and thus connection) is closed once the generator is no longer required.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Foo>> LazyQueryAllFoos()
{
   // NB : No `using` ... the reader controls the lifetime of the connection.
   var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
   // Yes, it is OK to dispose of the Command https://stackoverflow.com/a/744307/314291
   using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
        $"SELECT Col1, Col2, ... FROM LargeFoos", mySqlConn))
   {
      await mySqlConn.OpenAsync();
      var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
      // Return the IEnumerable, without actually materializing Foos yet.
      // Reader and Connection remain open until caller is done with the enumerable
      return GenerateFoos(reader);
   }
}

// Helper method to manage lifespan of foos
private static IEnumerable<Foo> GenerateFoos(IDataReader reader)
{
    using(reader)
    {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
          yield return new Foo
          {
              Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
              ...
          };
       }
    } // Reader is Closed + Disposed here => Connection also Closed.
}
```

**Notes**

- As at C#6, `async` code cannot currently also use yield return, hence the need to split the helper method out of the async query (The helper could I believe be moved into a Local Function, however).
- The code calling `GenerateFoos` does need to be mindful not to hold onto the Enumerable (or an Iterator of it) for longer than needed, as this will keep the underlying Reader and Connection open.

Comment: Nb don't scope a using around Conn or reader. Don't need $ string