# Using on an object created in a different method

Tags: c#, using

I'm trying to make a generic SQL call, which led me to an interesting question. I have a method that executes the SQL, and returns a `SQLDataReader`.

```
    private SqlDataReader ExecuteSql(SqlCommand command)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionText, Credentials))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            return command.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
```

The calling command takes the reader and processes the returned data correctly. However, knowing that the reader needs to be disposed of, I enclosed it in a `using` statement.

```
        using (SqlDataReader reader = ExecuteSql(command))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                try { ... }
                catch(Exception e) { ... }
            }
        }
```

I think `Dispose` should be called on the `SqlDataReader` at the end of the `using` statement despite where in the code it was created. However, I have not been able to find anything that specifically confirms this.

Generalizing, can the `using` statement be successfully used on an object that was created elsewhere in the code?

As a side note, I do realize that if the `SqlDataReader` was created as an object in the `ExecuteSql` method rather than returned directly, then there could be an issue with it throwing an exception while in the `ExecuteSql` method and not being disposed of.

Comment: In general *no characteristic of an **object** depends on the code location in which it is created*. However that is not true of **variables**; characteristics of variables such as guaranteed lifetime *do* depend on where the variable is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to use the object created in another method in the using statement.
However, in your case, you are using an `SqlDataReader` which uses the `SqlConnection` which is disposed at the end of the `ExecuteSql` call.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797839/can-i-keep-a-sqldatareader-alive-after-closing-connection), you need a valid connection object to use the `SqlDataReader`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and pointing out the error that I didn't catch, but should have.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this by passing an Action like so:

```
private void ExecuteSql(SqlCommand command, Action<SqlDataReader> action)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionText, Credentials))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            action(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the calling function:

```
var myCommand = //...

int id;

ExecuteSql(myCommand, (reader) => {
  id = reader.GetInt32(0);
});
```

Now any caller doesn't need to know if they have to dispose of it or not and your connection will be disposed after the method has done it work on the reader.

Comment: While [Zdeslav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58564105/18192) answered the OP's specific question, I think the architecture suggested in this answer is far superior to the approach the OP is taking.  That said, I would rather use a generic `private T ExecuteSql<T>` that accepts a `Func<SqlDataReader,T>`.  You can get a bit fancier by having the `Func` process only a single row, than having various collection-specific variations on `ExecuteSql`.

Comment: @Brian I'm in complete agreement.  Without any context, this solution isn't limited to `SqlDataReader` as it can be used with anything disposable, which is more of where I was going with it based on the Title to the question.