# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open ! asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 tier web site asp.net c#. I want to select user and check his user-type for login.but my code not work. and above error shown. pleas help me  what do I do.
my code DAL:

```
public SqlDataReader select_user(string UserName)
        {
            connect.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE UserName=@UserName", connect);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return dr;
        }
```

and BL:

```
 public SqlDataReader Get_user()
        {
            return da.select_user(UserName);
        }
```

and code of interface:

```
 try
        {

            bll.UserName = UserNameTextBox.Text;
            Session.Add("_UserName", bll.UserName);
            bll.Get_user();
            SqlDataReader dr = bll.Get_user();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();
                int Utyp = bll.UserTyp;
                if (Utyp == 0)
                {
                    Session.Add("Msg_", "dear user. you are unactive yet");
                    Response.Redirect("ShowMessage.aspx", false);
                }
                else
                    if (Utyp == 1)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("index.aspx", false);
                    }

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Session.Add("Msg_", "  : <br>" + ex.Message);
             Response.Redirect("~/ShowMessage.aspx");
         }
```

Comment: can you use using statement to wrap all ado.net objects like using() {} and that will take care to close and dispose the objects

Comment: Did the answer work for you @reza ?

Answer (score 1):

```
connect.Open();
```

should be changed to:

```
if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
    connect.Open();
}
```

to ensure that it tries to open the connection only once, rather than multiple times.

*Note that you may also wish to consider adding `using` statements as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744069/34092).*