# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'

Tags: c#, mysql

```
MySqlCommand Sql1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM animal WHERE idAnimal ='" + label1.Text + "'", Connection);

MySqlDataReader dr1;
dr1 = Sql1.ExecuteReader();

while (dr1.Read())
{
    String idAnimal = dr1["idAnimal"].ToString();

    MySqlCommand Sql2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM town WHERE id ='" + idAnimal + "'", Connectio);
    MySqlDataReader dr2;
    dr2 = Sql2.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr2.Read())
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr2["number"], dr2["name"]);
    }

    dr2.Close();
}

dr1.Close();
Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Why not just read all the idAnimal values into an array first, then close the first reader? Also, it makes no sense to "SELECT *" when you're only using the single field... and that field is the field that you're passing in as a condition.

Comment: Gah! The sql injection hole, it burns us!

Answer (score 2):

The **best** way to solve this is with a **JOIN** (and fix that *HUGE* sql injection hole while we're at it):

```
string sql = "SELECT t.number, t.name FROM animal a INNER JOIN town t ON t.ID = a.idAnimal WHERE a.idAnimal= @idAnimal";

using (var cn = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@idAnimal", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = int.Parse(label1.Text);

    cn.Open();
    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr["number"], dr["name"]);
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
}
```

Additionally, you should probably look into **databinding** to connect those results to your grid, rather than manually adding rows. That would let you write code like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT t.number, t.name FROM animal a INNER JOIN town t ON t.ID = a.idAnimal WHERE a.idAnimal= @idAnimal";
using (var cn = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@idAnimal", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = int.Parse(label1.Text);
    cn.Open();
    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dr;
        dr.Close();
    }
}
```

But if you *really* want to know how to have two DataReaders active together, you do that by having two connection objects:

```
using (var cn1 = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var sql1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM animal WHERE idAnimal = @idAnimal", cn1))
{
    sql1.Parameters.Add("@idAnimal", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = int.Parse(label1.Text);
    cn1.Open();
    using (var dr1 = sql1.ExecuteReader())
    {    
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            String idAnimal = dr1["idAnimal"].ToString();

            using (var cn2 = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
            using (var sql2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM town WHERE id = @idAnimal", cn2))
            {
                cn2.Parameters.Add("@idAnimal", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = int.Parse(idAnimal);
                cn2.Open();
                using(var dr2 = sql2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr2.Read())
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr2["number"], dr2["name"]);
                    }
                    dr2.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        dr1.Close();
    }
}
```

But note how this is more than twice as much code as the JOIN + DataBinding option.

Also note that it's **poor practice** in ADO.Net providers to keep one database connection for re-use in your application. In addition to limiting your ability to use multiple database queries at the same time, as we see here, ADO.Net uses a feature called `Connection Pooling`, and re-using the same connection object interferes with this. It really is better to create a *new connection object* in most cases, and simply re-use the connection string.

Comment: Finally got it!! "multiple database queries at the same time" That's why not to reuse a connection object but, as far as connection pooling, it is my understanding that the connection is returned to the pool as soon as it is closed. How does it interfere with pooling?

Comment: Soft of. It's really simple: **do not re-use the same object throughout your application**. It's not that hard to create new objects, and ADO.Net makes this process _faster_ for your application than re-use would be.

Comment: But re-using the same object interferes with pooling because it's possible for a stale connection to be invalidated, or disposed. With a re-used connection object, you can end up trying to re-open a disposed item, which will cause problems in the application.

Comment: Faster. Great, I didn't know that. I guess my view was very myopic as my data layer is all mine. Thank you.

Comment: If you're substituting a `Label1.Text` value directly into the sql string, there is no data layer.

Comment: I was referring to my experience. No `Imports System.Data.SqlClient `allowed except in my Data classes.

Comment: And as Joel himself commented on [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744069/5198140), those data reader `Close`s are not required and can be removed.

Comment: **Technically,** for data reader objects, the `.Close()` _is_ supposed to be there, because the documentation for their `Dispose()` method doesn't explicitly promise to close them. This is in contrast to connection objects, where `Dispose()` does promise to close them. **Practically**, I have a hard time imagining a disposed reader that is somehow still open, and I've never seen or heard of it causing a problem if you skip the `Close()` call. Because of the technical side, I've started using `Close()` in my Stack Overflow answers; I want to leave better artifacts behind in my posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same "Connection" variable in two commands at the same time.  Just have to create a second one if you want to open another connection inside of the Read of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same connection for the DataReader and the ExecuteNonQuery.which is not supported, according to MSDN You have to create sperate connection for each datareader

Comment: While this statement is correct, if you want to refer to MSDN, you should provide a link to the specific article or resource.