# DataGridView not showing data when i use while loop or if statement

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from AccountTbl where EmployeeCode=" + comboBox1.Text, con);
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = (dr["Status"].ToString());
            }
            dt.Load(dr);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Enter");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961938/populate-data-table-from-data-reader

Answer (score 0):

So when debugging your snippet, you should be able to see, that there is data read by the [`dr.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_Read).

And while reading your DataReader `dr.Read()` will consume all incoming data rows one-by-one. And within your `while`-loop you will operate with the received data.

```
// Get data row by row
while (dr.Read())
{
     // Displays the current "Status" content in your textbox
     textBox1.Text = (dr["Status"].ToString());
}
```

And when it now comes to creating your `DataTable` with [`Load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=netframework-4.8). The reader has just finished reading and hasn't any row left to read.

```
dt.Load(dr);
```

So your displayed DataGrid will be empty.

---

*As a hint:

I recommend wrapping your data reader in a using block like*

```
using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (dr.Read())
   {
      //Processing
   }

   // or

   dt.Load(dr);
}
```

*This will close and dispose your data reader.
You may take a look at 
[Is it necessary to manually close and dispose of SqlDataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744069/5893316)*